# Can't Enable Email/Password Sign in method in Firebase Authentication

Tags: firebase-authentication, firebase-console

I tried to enable Email/Password sign in method in Firebase Auth. When I click on the save button it gives error "Error updating Email/Password".

Please look at this image:

[image: Error]

I already added Firebase to my Android app.

Comment: Is there any additional information showing in the JavaScript console of your browser? If not, I recommend disabling any browser extensions you may have, running in an incognito window, or in another browser altogether. If none of these helps, [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thank you very much.I think it was due to a browser extension. I used inconigto window and it works for me. I wasted a day because of this  issue.Thank you very much again.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This problem usually happens if you are using an Antivirus, VPN, or proxy as this might block your connection so I recommend disabling them all.

Try to disable all your browser extensions as they might also block your connection.

If all the above steps did not work, try using a different browser preferably Google Chrome with an incognito window as Frank van Puffelen mentioned in the comments.

Comment: Yes correct. One of my Chrome plugins was blocking. Had to disable it and it works.

Answer (score 3):

remove CORS extensions from browser. and any other proxy or vpn from extensions then reload page.

Comment: What is this answer providing that was not provided by https://stackoverflow.com/a/66989038/12846804 posted 2 years before yours?

Answer (score 0):

Done. The same issue happened in my system also.
Disable the Cors Chrome (browser) extension
In the console[network tab] panel also we get a cors issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).